# Vite.js not emitting HTML files in multi page app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a multi page app that I'm trying to build with `Vite.js` (migrating from `Webpack`). When building the Vite + React example code I see that it emits:

- `dist/index.html`
- `dist/assets/<various assets>`

However, when I try to make a multi page app as shown [in the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) none of the HTMLs are emitted (but the rest of the content of `/assets/` is there). Why is this?

```js
// vite.config.js excerpt:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'client',
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url + 'index.html')),
        login: dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url + 'login.html')),
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: remove `dirname` which is removing the filename only directory names will be left out.

Comment: @Chandan If I remove dirname I get an error during `vite build` that says `SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue`.

Comment: try `new URL(`./index.html`, import.meta.url)` as specified in the [vite doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url).

Comment: Your suggestion worked @Chandan ! Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.
`main: new URL('./client/index.html', import.meta.url).pathname,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `URL` for file input as specified in [vite doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url)

```
main: new URL('./client/index.html', import.meta.url).pathname
```